# How to get time zone offset from IANA time zone code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zone code like "Asia/Kolkata" and I need to get time zone offset like -330 in JavaScript. I am not able to get time zone offset any help will be appriciated.

Comment: @OmSao getTimezoneOffset() on Date() object will give time zone offset of browser's timezone I need time zone offset of specific IANI time zone offset like "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: You need to use some JS framework then, like moment.js or TimeZoneJS

With only javascript, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to get time zone offset from IANA time zone code in javascript. I have used [moment-timezone-with-data.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js) as below

```
var zone = moment.tz.zone('Asia/Kolkata');
zone.parse(Date.UTC(2012, 2, 19, 8, 30)); // -330
```

Comment: This isn't really a solution in the 2020s, because that library has been deprecated. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status

Comment: @MichaelScheper I saw the npm moment-timezone lib get updated 6 mo ago. Is that lib okay to use?

Answer (score 4):

Using the native `Date.toLocaleString` API:

```js
function timeZoneOffsetInMinutes(ianaTimeZone) {
  const now = new Date();
  now.setSeconds(0, 0);

  // Format current time in `ianaTimeZone` as `M/DD/YYYY, HH:MM:SS`:
  const tzDateString = now.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: ianaTimeZone,
    hourCycle: 'h23',
  });

  // Parse formatted date string:
  const match = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+), (\d+):(\d+)/.exec(tzDateString);
  const [_, month, day, year, hour, min] = match.map(Number);

  // Change date string's time zone to UTC and get timestamp:
  const tzTime = Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, min);

  // Return the offset between UTC and target time zone:
  return Math.floor((tzTime - now.getTime()) / (1000 * 60));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to take advantage of your question and promote moment.js which is a great date/time library which supportedny feature I ever needed.
For example see:

moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata").offset(...)

For timezones

Comment: I would recommend against including moment.js in new projects, because the maintainers of that library have announced that it is deprecated. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ The announcement comes with a list of suggested alternatives, including not using a library. I landed on this question while websearching to see whether there is a native JS solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [tzdb](https://github.com/vvo/tzdb/) library, which promises to be kept up-to-date with the IANA database.

```
const kolkataTimeZone = timeZones.find( ({name}) => name === 'Asia/Kolkata' );
console.log(kolkataTimeZone.rawOffsetInMinutes); // 330
```

Note that, unlike the deprecated *moment.js* library, offsets are logically signed, i.e. time zones behind UTC (mainly the Americas) are negative and time zones ahead of UTC (the majority of the world population) are positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/), which is a good alternative to the deprecated moment library

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

dayjs.tz(undefined, 'Asia/Kolkata').format('ZZ')
```

Comment: dont forget to extend
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

Comment: @ihorbond good call! Just edited

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do it with [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon/)

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
    
export function getOffsetFromIANATimezone (ianaTimezone: string): number {
  const dt =DateTime.now().setZone(ianaTimezone)
  return (dt.offset / 60)
}
```