# How to get UTC offsets from time zones of a particular region?

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a small list of time zones as shown below. It also has the IANA names for time zones.

How do I use javascript to get the UTC offset for these time zones for the current time? I can use libraries like dayjs also, but I prefer plain js. I could not find any answers for this. Here is the closest question I could find [How to get UTC Offset from a timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441076/how-to-get-utc-offset-from-a-timezone). But, it has no answers.

```
1 - Pacific Standard Time, America/Los_Angeles
    Expected utc offset = -420
2 - Eastern Standard Time, America/New_York
    Expected utc offset = -240
```

Comment: "How do I use javascript to get the utc offset for these time zones?" The UTC offset at which instant in time? (The UTC offset for most time zones varies over time...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - UTC offset for the current time. Thanks

Comment: Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69014377/20366099 - Does this answer this question appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Intl` specification includes a `timeZoneName` option for the [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) constructor that controls how the time zone name is formatted.  One of the options is `'longOffset'`, which is suitable for this purpose. Also, a clean way to isolate that string is to use the [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) function.

```js
function getCurrentOffset(timeZone) {

  // Create the formatter with the desired options.
  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    timeZone,
    timeZoneName: 'longOffset'});

  // Get the time zone name component, and slice off any leading abbreviation.
  const offsetString = format.formatToParts()
    .find(p => p.type === 'timeZoneName')
    .value
    .slice(3);

  // UTC and its equivalents must be handled directly, because Intl will return 'GMT'.
  if (offsetString === '') {
    return {offsetString: '+00:00', offsetMinutes: 0};
  }

  // Parse the hours and minutes from the result.
  const hours = offsetString.slice(0, 3);
  const minutes = offsetString.slice(4);
  const offsetMinutes = (-hours * 60) + ((hours < 0 ? 1 : -1) * minutes);

  // Return the ISO 8601 formatted offset string, as well as the total minutes offset.
  // Note, this returns minutes inverted, to match the behavior of the Date.getTimezoneOffset function.
  return {offsetString, offsetMinutes};
}

// some examples
console.log('America/Los_Angeles', getCurrentOffset('America/Los_Angeles'));
console.log('America/New_York', getCurrentOffset('America/New_York'));
console.log('Asia/Kolkata', getCurrentOffset('Asia/Kolkata'));
console.log('Pacific/Marquesas', getCurrentOffset('Pacific/Marquesas'));
console.log('Etc/UTC', getCurrentOffset('Etc/UTC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. get formatted string with timezone offset with `Date.toLocaleString`
2. parse it and calculate an offset in minutes

```js
function getTimezoneOffset(timeZone){
  const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en', {timeZone, timeZoneName: 'longOffset'});
  const [_,h,m] = str.match(/([+-]\d+):(\d+)$/) || [, '+00', '00'];
  return h * 60 + (h > 0 ? +m : -m);
}

'America/Los_Angeles America/New_York Asia/Kolkata Pacific/Marquesas Etc/UTC'.match(/\S+/g).forEach(tz => 
  console.log(tz, getTimezoneOffset(tz))
);
```